# Java, Android Development, Intent to a xml file

Tags: java, android

How can I Create an Intent like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ColorsActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

That will open a XML file. I tried replace the `ColorsActivity.class` with `activity_number.xml` but it just doesn't work for me.

Comment: What do you mean "open a XML file"? What would you like to achieve?

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: Open a xml file instead of a Java file

Comment: Open an XML file using what? A third-party app for browsing XML?

Comment: ok you mean displaying the content of a XML file...right?

Answer (score 0):

XML files are not screens in an application that you can just open. They can represent any number of things, from a single `View` in a layout, to the layout for a `Fragment` or an entire `Activity`. Android doesn't know what you want to do with it.

You need to create a new `Activity` class that uses your XML file as its layout (via `setContentView()`) if you want to open a new Activity with that layout.

Answer (score 0):

U cannot call .xml file directly from intent. U have to call an .class that uses .xml onCreate().